# Safari reader

Tags: objective-c, ios, safari

Ребята, у кого есть iphone на 5.0.1 знают что такое функция "Reader"

Вопрос таков, я делаю парсинг, зачем все что мне нужно вывожу через WebView. Сами понимаете что масштабируется только тест и масштабируется он по желанию самого WebView. Функция "Reader" была бы тут, ну просто офигительно востребована. Во-первых, все картинки и причие подгоняется под размер, а во-вторых, пользователь может сам увеличивать и уменьшать текст.

Ну а теперь вопрос. Есть ли способы вызвать эту функцию, или есть подобные ей???
Зарание спасибо за любую информацию, критику и конечно же минусы =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможность работать с Safari Reader появилась с ios9, с помощью Safari View Controller. Но, к счастью, есть другой способ, который применим ко всем предыдущим версиям ios, это преобразовать текст к читабельному виду, использую такие вещи как: `Readability Mobilizer`, `Instapaper Mobilizer`, или `Google Mobilizer`. Они выполняют тоже самое, что и Safari Reader. Пример использования `Readability Mobilizer` - имея ссылку, в которой вы хотите выполнить преобразования, помещаете в конец другой ссылки -

```
http://www.readability.com/m?url=http://{URLOFTHEARTICLE}
```

и передаете ее вашему UIWebView.